# In D&D 4E, can a changeling change its biological sex?

Tags: dnd-4e

Simply put, can a Changeling change its sex... physically?

Specifically, I had an incident where a female PC tried to change into a male but I told her that a Changeling can't change 'reproductive organs'. Just wondering if I was wrong at that point.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Yes**,

The Changeling Disguise ability reads:

> **Effect**: You alter your physical form to take on the appearance of any Medium humanoid.

It is not restricted to any medium humanoid of the same sex.

Also, note the suggested names for Changelings in the book.  Unlike the other races, they are not separated by sex.  Changelings have just one list of names.

From the *Eberron Player's Guide* pg 29

> A changeling who travels frequently might change identities from town to town, swapping **genders**, appearances, and voices to blend in within each new community.

Just noticed that all of the above is also in the [DDI entry for Changeling](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/race.aspx?id=14).  I didn't realize they added that much of the supplemental material there.

As to answering questions like:

- Can a changeling's parts functional?
- Can a changeling conceive regardless of his/her original sex?
- Does it matter if a changeling polymorphs while pregnant?

While they are interesting questions, the game as written doesn't specify how reproduction happens for **any** race.  We can't answer questions about what happens when a dwarf and an elf "get together", much less the particulars of changeling reproduction!  @Brian's answer gives excellent guidance as to what you and your group can do to figure things out if you want to go down that road.

Answer (score 11):

**It Depends.**

As @Pat noted, DDI indicates you can change gender. And the spell is a polymorph spell, which means that physical changes do take place. It would be difficult to disguise yourself via polymorph without taking the external sexual characteristics of the race into account. (Or removing them, in the case of lizardpeople.)

However, the *fundamental* question is one of the social contract between players and DM, because this is something that can completely and totally break immersion for some groups. While impersonating someone of the other sex is fine, (and I'm absolutely not getting into the silly prescriptivist debate between sex and gender), the question of bringing a child to bear as someone polymorphed into the other sex is one that is absolutely and completely under the DM's control.

Therefore, if a player tries this during your game, allowing them to look as if they're "Lady Such and Such" when they're a male rogue is fine. If they try to go *further* than that, ask them to table their plans for now and to chat with you after the game over coffee (or beverage of your choice.) Here, as in all contracts, the boundaries need to be drawn regarding the use of and the depiction of the act of sex in a game. I would be quite shocked if the player playing as a male character would want to carry a child within them for any non-trivial length of time, as that would basically stop the character adventuring. In short form, if they want to have sex, the most trivial thing to do is fade to black, and resume the story, as the biological consequences of sex are unlikely to be directly interesting to the plot.

However, in the right group, a story about the genetic nature of changelings could make for a very interesting philosophical exploration, if handled well. While this is a world-setting toggle "how do changelings have children?" the consequences are *fascinating* any way one sets the toggle. This topic *absolutely must* be unanimously agreed upon by the group beforehand, and is not a topic for a newbie DM nor a group that has people with extremely strong feelings on the topic.

My recommendation, if Changelings don't feature in your game except as a PC race is to assume that they have normal biological workings, are infertile except with people of their own species, and can mimic the external sexual characteristics (and appropriate mental responses) of any race their power covers.

If changelings do feature in your game, absolutely explore the question of how they reproduce, figure out the consequences, and then have it be part of their background or a clue in a plot.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

From 'Races of Eberron', Page 45 : 
"A changeling can alter his or her gender (and reproductive abilities) as part of using the race's minor shapechange ability."
"If a changeling in a female form conceives a child, she loses the ability to change her gender until after the child is born."

Unless there is something in 4e overriding that content.

Comment: 3.X content has no bearing on 4e.

Comment: Fluff does not always change across D&D editions, I think an answer from a previous edition properly labeled as such is a good answer. If the slate was wiped clean of all Ecology articles, etc. every time the game revved we'd be the poorer for it. This is about a specific race in a specific game world, and I similarly would assume that it tended to apply in new editions lacking specific contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**About the gender:** Changelings can any take any humanoid form and gender (if a humanoid race has no gender or is transgendered or anything similar then that too), this is no illusion, it is a real change.

**About pregnancy:** Changelings are themselves natural descendants of the Doppelganger and Human races, their organs truly change, and these two facts mean they can be pregnant, or make others pregnant. The offspring is most likely always a Changeling itself.

Comment: do you have a source for this?

Comment: @waxeagle Races of Eberron, pg 45. Only error there is that the children have equal chances to be a changeling or the race of the other parent.

Answer (score -2):

It's a physical and biological change; if antimagical effects affect the outcome then it falls under transmutation. So in effect they can carry a child, but to mutate into another form while doing so would have a wide range of outcomes:

- Early pregnancy: You should be fine switching to other races of a similar reproductive anatomy, i.e. elf, human, orc, even ogre are humanoid mammals with similar organs and their placement, therefore safe.

  Mammal to an egg-laying biology is only likely to work in the early stages of conception, likely within 24-48hrs, and once an egg is laid you should be good, but the changes in the offspring would possibly show some of the form of the egg-laying biology as well, probably 'safe'.

  Changing into a male would cause the body to reject the fetus as unknown matter, mostly like an internal infection, probably very sickening and possibly deadly in some cases.
- Mid-pregnancy: Same as above.

  Egg-laying biology would likely be much like a mammal's miscarriage.

  Changing into a male is probably suicide without immediate surgery, which is lacking in D&D's timeline era.
- Late pregnancy: Same. Congratulations on your soon to be newborn.

  Egg-layer, congratulations on your safe recovery from an 'abortion'.

  Male? I think we'll cremate the body, it's seen *much* better days (particularly if you were a 7' beast of a girl, and decided to go out as male halfling mashed taters).